# Incomplete Datatable Export to csv with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, csv, join, export

PowerShell 5.1

I am joining to datatable $dt_1 and $dt_2 into a new datatable $merged with this code:

```
$merged = $dt_1 | ForEach-Object {
$dt1Row = $_
$dt2Rows = $dt_2 | Where-Object { $_."Facility" -eq $dt1Row."Facility" -and $_."Customer" -eq $dt1Row."Customer" -and $_."Contract" -eq $dt1Row."Contract" }

$resultObject = $dt1Row | Select-Object  "Contract", "Customer ","Contract"
$Count = 1

foreach ($dt2Row in $dt2Rows) {
    $resultObject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name ("Material - $Count") -Value $dt2Row.Material
    $resultObject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name ("Material_Number - $Count") -Value $dt2Row.'Material_Number'
    $Count ++

}

$resultObject
}
```

$dt_2 has multiple entries for the key stored in $dt1: Facility, Customer, Contract.

When I output $merged with

```
$merged | Format-Table -AutoSize
```

in the console I get exactly the view I want to export to a CSV:

| Facility | Customer | Contract | Material - 1 | Material_Number - 1 | Material - 2 | Material_Number - 2 | Material - 3 | Material_Number - 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Fac_A | Customer_X | Contract_X | Material_A | Material_Number_123 | Material_B | Material_Number_234 | Material_C | Material_Number_564 |
| Fac_A | Customer_Y | Contract_Y | Material_A | Material_Number_123 | Material_B | Material_Number_234 |  |  |

But if I export $merged to csv via

```
$merged | Export-Csv "\Path\To\CSV.csv" -NoType -Delimiter ";" -Encoding UTF8
```

I get only the values up to 1 in the CSV:

| Facility | Customer | Contract | Material - 1 | Material_Number - 1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Fac_A | Customer_X | Contract_X | Material_A | Material_Number_123 |
| Fac_A | Customer_Y | Contract_Y | Material_A | Material_Number_123 |

What is the reason for this and can I force a complete export to csv?

Comment: Unfortunately `Export-Csv` (much like `Format-Table`) defines the columns based on the first object in the array that is piped to it. I'm guessing that your first item only has 1 material listed, so everything after that is getting truncated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment, I'm guessing that your missing properties are due to the first item in your collection not having as many properties as other items. I have a slightly different solution to your process, but it still iterates `$dt_2`, validating against `$dt_1` (which it appears you are doing). It groups things up, finds the largest group, and then creates objects for each grouping with the number of materials the largest group has (just having empty values in the extra columns).
First I simulated tables similar to what you had in your examples. I added a couple to the first table to include a same customer/different facility to show how that would output, and a customer with no match in table `$dt_2`. I also added a row in `$dt_2` with no match in `$dt_1` to show that it gets excluded from the output like it would with your code.

```
$dt_1=@'
"Facility","Customer","Contract"
"Seattle","Cust_A","C1"
"Chicago","Cust_A","C1"
"Chicago","Cust_B","C2"
"Dallas","Cust_C","C3"
"Dallas","Cust_D","C2"
'@|convertfrom-csv

$dt_2=@'
"Facility","Customer","Contract","Material","Material_Number"
"Seattle","Cust_A","C1","M1","123"
"Chicago","Cust_B","C2","M1","123"
"Seattle","Cust_A","C1","M2","456"
"Dallas","Cust_C","C3","M2","456"
"Dallas","Cust_C","C3","M4","789"
"Chicago","Cust_A","C1","M2","456"
"Chicago","Cust_A","C1","M5","000"
"Seattle","Cust_D","C2","M4","789"
'@|ConvertFrom-Csv
```

Now I group up `$dt_2`, find the largest group, and make objects for all of the groups.

```
$Grouped = $dt_2|where{$dt_1 -match ($_|select "Facility","Customer","Contract")}|group Facility,Custom,Contract
$MaxGroup = $Grouped|measure-object -Maximum -Property Count|% Maximum
$Results = $Grouped|%{
    $objOut = $_.Group[0] |Select "Facility", "Customer","Contract"
    For($i=0;$i -lt $MaxGroup;$i++){
        Add-Member -InputObject $objOut -NotePropertyName "Material - $($i+1)" -NotePropertyValue $_.group[$i].Material
        Add-Member -InputObject $objOut -NotePropertyName "Material_Number - $($i+1)" -NotePropertyValue $_.group[$i].Material_Number
    }
    $objOut
}
```

Here's the results piped to `Format-Table` and `ConvertTo-Csv` (you could use `Export-Csv` the same to write to file instead of screen)

```
PS C:\Users\TMTech> $Results | Format-Table -AutoSize

Facility Customer Contract Material - 1 Material_Number - 1 Material - 2 Material_Number - 2
-------- -------- -------- ------------ ------------------- ------------ -------------------
Seattle  Cust_A   C1       M1           123                 M2           456                
Chicago  Cust_B   C2       M1           123                                                 
Dallas   Cust_C   C3       M2           456                 M4           789                
Chicago  Cust_A   C1       M2           456                 M5           000                

PS C:\Users\TMTech> $Results | convertto-csv -NoTypeInformation -Delimiter ';'

"Facility";"Customer";"Contract";"Material - 1";"Material_Number - 1";"Material - 2";"Material_Number - 2"
"Seattle";"Cust_A";"C1";"M1";"123";"M2";"456"
"Chicago";"Cust_B";"C2";"M1";"123";;
"Dallas";"Cust_C";"C3";"M2";"456";"M4";"789"
"Chicago";"Cust_A";"C1";"M2";"456";"M5";"000"
```

Notice that the first and last results are both Cust_A, just for different facilities, showing what materials are used at which facility.